# how to use grep function for search?

Tags: r, regex

I want to build build a function which allows me to identify days from any string. My days directory is:

```
days<-c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")
```

The search should be case insensitive but should not include partial matches such as Mon for Monday or Tues for Tuesday.

For example, below mentioned string should give me results as noted below.

```
string<-"Wednesday mon Tuesday Thraus Friday"
```

Expected result:

```
result<-c("Tuesday","Wednesday", "Friday")
```

My code:

```
days<-c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")

string<-("WednesdayTuesday Mon Thraus Friday")
string<-strsplit(string, " ", fixed=TRUE)
string<-unlist(string)  
result<- unique (grep(paste(tolower(string), collapse = "|"), tolower(days), value = TRUE))
# [1] "monday"    "tuesday"   "wednesday" "friday"
```

How can I use to `grep` function to get expected result? Thanks!

Comment: Should there be a space between `Wednesday` and `Tuesday`?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_extract_all` after `paste`ing the 'days' vector as a single string for the `pattern`

```
library(stringr)
pat <- paste0("\\b(", paste(days, collapse="|"), ")\\b")
str_extract_all(string, pat))[[1]]
#[1] "Wednesday" "Tuesday"   "Friday"
```

---

Or in `base R` with `regmatches/gregexpr`

```
regmatches(string, gregexpr(pat, string))[[1]]
#[1] "Wednesday" "Tuesday"   "Friday"   '
```

#### data

```
days<-c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")
string <- "Wednesday mon Tuesday Thraus Friday"
```